# Is android bug in load "layout-ldltr" layout against "layout-ldrtl" after orientation changed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, right-to-left, left-to-right

In my project I have to create both `layout-ldltr` and `layout-ldrtl` layouts for `Right-To-Left` and `Left-To-Right` languages.

I launch application for Right-To-Left language, and every thing is good.
But when orientation changed, android load `layout-ldltr` layout against `layout-ldrtl`, although current `Locale` is set to RTL language!!!

How can fix this problem?

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".QuranApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In `layout-ldrtl\activity_main.xml` :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layoutDirection="rtl">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

    <include
        layout="@layout/list_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

After @JohanShogun comment, I change `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to `android:layoutDirection="locale"`and problem solved for most items.

In first photo all element are shown very good:

[image: Portrait orientation]

In landscape mode, in [StickyListHeader list view](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) in header item that sticking at top of screen, Android used from **ltr** layout!:

[image: Lanscape orientation]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a folder with layout-land it will take president over layout-ldrtl etc. you may need to create folders for layout-land-ldrtl and so on.

An other way you can handle your right-to-left and left-to-right layouts is to keep one layout file which is written to work with both versions.

On a LinearLayout etc there is an attribute:

```
android:layoutDirection
```

You can set this to the value of "Locale" and your horizontal layouts will flip order.

Instead of using `align_left/align_right` and `gravity_left/gravity_right` use instead `align_start/align_end` and `gravity_start/gravity_end` (goes for all `left/right` attributes). The start and end tags depend on the layout direction. If the user has a locale with `ltr` *start is left* and *end is right*, if the user has a locale with `rtl` *start is right* and *end is left*.

I personally prefer using layout files that are written to work with both `rtl` and `ltr` over having separate ones, it's easy to miss an update in one version if you keep different files, resulting in a bad user experience.

Also move your layout to the layout folder (remove `"-ldrtl"`) then change all `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` to `android:layoutDirection="locale"`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I added android:layoutDirection attribute, but not affect for this problem.

Comment: if you use the android layout attribute you may want to skip your folders with rtl/ltr resources. Also please show your code with how you used the attribute

Comment: also remember to put this in your application manifest: android:supportsRtl="true" (goes on application level) http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: I edit question and add my code for your recommendations.

Comment: Try this: Move your layout to the layout folder (remove "-ldrtl") then change all android:layoutDirection="rtl" to android:layoutDirection="locale"

Comment: Very good, your comment solve problem for some layouts.
please edit your answer and add this solution to it.
I add screenshot to next answer to show result.

Comment: Updated the answer, I'm not sure if you have more issues though? You may want to consider doing the same changes for your landscape layouts. The sticky header item may not have rtl support. If so you can probably add it quite easy by modifying it's resource files.

Comment: I post an issue to github page of Sticky ListHeader plugin:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/issues/417

Thank you again for your helps and replies :)

Comment: Alright :) if you think you can, consider attempting to fix the bug yourself and contributing it to the library. Either way, if this resolves all your non library related issues, please accept this answer. :)